# How to properly do model testing with ActiveStorage in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activestorage

I have just switched to using ActiveStorage on rails 5.1.4 and I am new to TDD and struggling to figure out how to test a model that `has_one_attached :avatar`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do

  let (:valid_user) { FactoryBot.build(:user) }
  describe "Upload avatar" do
    context "with a valid image" do      
      it "saves the image" do
        valid_user.save!        
        saved_file = valid_user.avatar.attach(io: File.open("/home/ubuntu/workspace/spec/fixtures/files/avatar.jpg"), filename: "face.jpg", content_type: "image/jpg")
        expect(saved_file).to be_an_instance_of(ActiveStorage::Attachment::One)
      end
    end
  end 

end
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) User Upload avatar with a valid image saves the image
     Failure/Error:
       saved_file = valid_user.avatar.attach(io: File.open("/home/ubuntu/workspace/spec/fixtures/files/avatar.jpg"), filename: "face.jpg", 
                                             content_type: "image/jpg")


 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass
   Did you mean?  load
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activestorage-0.1/lib/active_storage/blob.rb:48:in `upload'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activestorage-0.1/lib/active_storage/blob.rb:21:in `block in build_after_upload'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activestorage-0.1/lib/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `tap'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activestorage-0.1/lib/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `build_after_upload'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activestorage-0.1/lib/active_storage/blob.rb:26:in `create_after_upload!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activestorage-0.1/lib/active_storage/attached.rb:25:in `create_blob_from'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activestorage-0.1/lib/active_storage/attached/one.rb:9:in `attach'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any hints?

Comment: TIP: `expect(valid_user.image.attached?).to be true` Because you don't need to test the internals of ActiveStorage.

Comment: `expect(valid_user.image).to be_attached` is the same but a bit more idiomatic RSpec

Answer (score 35):

I solved using

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :culture do
    name 'Soy'
    after(:build) do |culture|
      culture.image.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('spec', 'factories', 'images', 'soy.jpeg')), filename: 'soy.jpeg', content_type: 'image/jpeg')
    end
  end
end
```

After

```
describe '#image' do
  subject { create(:culture).image }

  it { is_expected.to be_an_instance_of(ActiveStorage::Attached::One) }
end
```

Comment: This gives you a possible false positive, since image will always be an instance of ActiveStorage::Attached::One, even when it is nil. Try the following in console: `User.new.avatar`. Notice that it is an instance of ActiveStorage::Attached::One.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch: but what is the solution then?

Answer (score 20):

Problem solved. After tracing the error to the ActiveStorage::Blob::upload method, where it said: `Uploads the io to the service on the key for this blob.` I realized I had not set the active_storage.service for the Test environment. Simply put, just add:

```
config.active_storage.service = :test
```

To config/environments/test.rb file

Comment: Tried the other answer with no joy - this worked for me, thanks

Comment: Any way to set this if some models have Paperclip and others Activestorage?

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I solved it

```
# model
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
end
```

```
# factory
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :report, class: Report do 
    any_extra_field { 'its value' }
  end
end
```

```
# spec
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Report, type: :model do
  context "with a valid file" do
    before(:each) do
      @report = create(:report)
    end

    it "is attached" do
      @report.file.attach(
        io: File.open(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'file_name.xlsx')),
        filename: 'filename.xlsx',
        content_type: 'application/xlsx'
      )
      expect(@report.file).to be_attached
    end
  end
end
```

I hope it help you

Comment: This was the better test for me, you actually check if the item is attached or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

With some help of these post I did an update of rspec test for active storage at rails 6.1

```
# .\spec\models\activestorage_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        @user.save!
        saved_file = @user.pictures.attach(io: File.open("./storage/test.jpg"), filename: "test.jpg", content_type: "image/jpg")
  end

  describe "Upload picture" do
    context "with a valid picture" do    

      it "saves the picture" do        
        expect(@user.pictures).to be_attached
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Now you can only add some more tests

Answer (score 4):

I was running into a similar nil error (Module::DelegationError: to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil), but it was only occurring when multiple tests were using the same factory.

The problem appears to be that the cleanup from the previous test's teardown was deleting the file after it was attached on the next factory call.  The key was updating the ActiveJob queue adapter to inline so that the file would be deleted right away.

Add both of these settings to config/environments/test.rb:

```
# Use inline job processing to make things happen immediately
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline

# Store uploaded files on the local file system in a temporary directory.
config.active_storage.service = :test
```

Comment: I just upgraded to rails 7.1 and this became an issue. Your post saved me!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In config/environments/test.rb

`config.active_storage.service = :test`

In your spec

`it {expect(valid_user.avatar).to be_attached}`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have used rails shoulda gem

```
it { should have_one_attached(:image) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'relations' do
    it { is_expected.to have_one(:avatar_attachment) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Rspec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'relations' do
    it { is_expected.to have_one_attached(:avatar_attachment) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.