# How to stub file size on Active Storage test? (Test::Unit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, testing, mocking, rails-activestorage

I'm using Active Storage in a [personal project](https://github.com/MatheusRich/dontfile). I want to check if the max size of files is being validated. I don't wanna use a real file, but I don't know how to stub an object.

Here's the test code:

```
test "should not upload file bigger than max size allowed" do
  refute @page.file.attached?

  patch "/#{@page.url}", params: {
    page: {
      url: "/#{@page.url}",
      file: my_stub_file_with_big_size
    }
  }
  assert_response :not_acceptable
  @page.reload

  refute  @page.file.attached?
end
```

Here's the validation on model:

```
def file_size
  if file.attached? && file.byte_size > MAX_FILE_SIZE
    file.purge
    errors.add(:file, "File is too big. Max size is 20mb.")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the code from your project, and I see that you've come up with an interesting solution, but here's another that matches your requirements.

## Step 1 - Add mocha

[Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) is the *de facto* stubbing library for MiniTest fans, so add it to your Gemfile like so.

```
group :test do
  gem 'mocha'
end
```

Then run `bundle install` and require mocha in your **test helper** like so:

```
# test/test_helper.rb

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

# add this line
require 'mocha/minitest'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase    
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all    
end
```

## Step 2 - Create a dummy test file

Place a small file named 'test.png' in `test/fixtures/files/`. Note that my file is around 20KB in size, it's pretty small.

## Step 3 - Add a unit test

Add the following to `test/models/page_test.rb`:

```
test 'file has max size' do
  # get the path of the file
  fixture_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'test.png')

  # open the file  
  fixture_file = File.open(fixture_path)

  # stub the file size to 21 MB
  fixture_file.stubs(:size).returns(21.megabytes)

  # attach the file to your @page instance
  @page.file.attach(io: fixture_file, filename: 'test.png')

  # the record should now be invalid
  refute @page.valid?

  # it should not have an attachment
  refute @page.file.attached?

  # assert the error message matches a regex 
  assert_match /is too big/, @page.errors[:file].to_s
end
```

## Step 4 - Test inside the maximum filesize boundary

Let's make sure that a file of 20MB **can** be accepted by adding the following to `test/models/page_test.rb`:

```
test 'file with valid size' do
  # get the path of the file
  fixture_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'test.png')

  # open the file  
  fixture_file = File.open(fixture_path)

  # stub the file size to 20 MB
  fixture_file.stubs(:size).returns(20.megabytes)

  # attach the file to your @page instance
  @page.file.attach(io: fixture_file, filename: 'test.png')

  # the record should now be valid
  assert @page.valid?

  # it should have an attachment
  assert @page.file.attached?

  # probably unnecessary, but let's test that there are no errors on @page
  assert_empty @page.errors[:file]
end
```

## Step 5 - Add a controller test for the happy path

Let's add a controller test for the happy path:

```
test 'should update page' do
  # fixture_file_upload knows where the fixtures folder is
  # and makes sure we have a correctly signed file
  fixture_file = fixture_file_upload('files/test.png', 'image/png')

  # we need to stub the byte_size of any instance of ActiveStorage::Blob
  # as that is what our validations are going to be run against 
  ActiveStorage::Blob.any_instance.stubs(:byte_size).returns(20.megabytes)

  # make sure our ActiveStorage records are created
  assert_difference ['ActiveStorage::Blob.count', 'ActiveStorage::Attachment.count'] do
    # add our fixture file into the params
    patch page_url, params: { page: { file: fixture_file } }
  end

  # make sure we are redirected to the right place 
  assert_redirected_to page_url
end
```

## Step 6 - Add a controller test for the sad path

Time to test upload failure:

```
test 'should render edit template when update fails' do
  # like before, we get correctly formatted test file by calling
  # fixture_file_upload method and passing in the test file
  fixture_file = fixture_file_upload('files/test.png', 'image/png')

  # stub the byte_size to be 21MB
  ActiveStorage::Blob.any_instance.stubs(:byte_size).returns(21.megabytes)

  # make sure zero ActiveStorage records are created
  assert_no_difference ['ActiveStorage::Blob.count', 'ActiveStorage::Attachment.count'] do
    # send the request
    patch page_url, params: { page: { file: fixture_file } }
  end

  # check the response body for an error message
  assert_match /is too big/, response.body.to_s
end
```

That's it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the detailed answer. Since it's so complete, I think you could open a pull request adding this. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to handle any custom validations on a given model in a separate class so my approach may not be for you. See the Rails documentation [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with) for more information.

In my custom validation class’ tests, I used Rspec’s `receive_message_chain` to stub any calls to the ActiveStorage image. For the model in question, I have a factory with a `with_image` trait defined (thanks to [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583883/how-to-properly-do-model-testing-with-activestorage-in-rails)), and then I stubbed the necessary calls on the model’s `image`. Unfortunately this requires having at least one image fixture in your test suite, but it can be any size you'd like. Full example below:

user.rb (model) - note the use of a custom `target` option

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image

  validates_with ImageValidator, target: :image
end
```

user.rb (factory)

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    trait :with_image do
      after(:build) do |user|
        user.image.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'user-image.png')), filename: 'user-image.png', content_type: 'image/png')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

image_validator.rb (validation class) - the custom `target` option is then used to determine which attribute on a given model this class should be used to validate.

```
class ImageValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if options[:target].present? && record.send(target).attached?
      if record.send(target).blob.byte_size > 1000000
        record.send(target).purge
        record.errors.add(:image, "Image too large")
      elsif !record.send(target).blob.content_type.starts_with?('image/')
        record.send(target).purge
        record.errors.add(:image, "Incorrect image format")
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def target
    options[:target].to_s
  end
end
```

image_validator_spec.rb (test)

```
require "rails_helper"

describe ImageValidator do
  subject { build(:user, :with_image) }

  context "when an Image is too large" do
    before do
      allow(subject.image).
        to receive_message_chain(:blob, :byte_size).and_return(1000001)
    end

    it "should be invalid" do
      expect(subject).to be_invalid
    end
  end
end
```